# npm-start not running in aws cloudformation user data

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, npm, aws-cloudformation, packer

I'm trying to run npm start in aws cloudformation user data like this:

```
nodejs = '\n', \
             'echo "starting node server" > /tmp/nodejs.log\n', \
             'npm run start-dev --prefix /data/app/myProject >> /tmp/nodejs.log &\n', \
             'echo "After starting node server" >> /tmp/nodejs.log', \
             '\n' ''
```

This is later put into userdata along with other commands.

Here is what I get in /tmp/nodejs.log after execution:

```
starting node server
After starting node server
```

The npm run command doesn't leave any logs and the server isn't started. If I run that command in the terminal then the server would run successfully.

Why isn't the npm-start command being executed?

**Follow up**

The reason the server isn't starting is because the npm command isn't recognized in the userdata script. I am however installing node via nvm in a packer provisioner script:

```
{
  "type": "shell",
  "script": "sh/install_node.sh",
  "execute_command": "chmod +x {{ .Path }}; sudo bash -c '{{ .Vars }} {{ .Path }}'"
}
```

Here's the install_node.sh file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#install nvm
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.34.0/install.sh | bash

export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion

#install node
nvm install 6.8.0
```

So now I'm trying to figure out why installing node via a packer provisioner script isn't enough for npm to be recognized in aws cloudformation userdata script.

Comment: Why are you using & ? I will suggest to save error out as well. # 'npm run start-dev --prefix /data/app/myProject >> /tmp/nodejs.log 2> /tmp/nodejs_err.log \n', \

Comment: Thanks for the heads up about using 2>. Now I can see that the error is this: npm: command not found. Not really sure how because I install node using 'nvm install' in one of my packer provisioner scripts.

Comment: @shantanuo I'm using & so the server would start in the background and not freeze the jenkins build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone stumbles upon this question, the solution is to simply add your node path to the PATH environment variable in cloudFormation, like so:

```
        nodejs = '\n', \
             'PATH=/root/.nvm/versions/node/v6.8.0/bin:$PATH\n', \
             'npm run start-dev --prefix path/to/project\n' \
             '\n' ''
```